# GETDATE() returns datepart only, and 00:00:00.000 for time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with near 100 columns, more than 1.000.000 rows, and the last column is:

```
[RecTime] AS DATETIME
```

where i store the date-time of every row made. This column has a :

```
... CONSTRAINT [DF_ZHMIA1A_RecTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RecTime]
```

everything works fine, new rows get the current date-time, for example.

```
'2012-12-03 11:23:46.126'
```

but sometimes after the insertion of a new row [RecTime] stores the date part only, such as

```
'2012-12-03 00:00:00.000'
```

any thoughts ?

here is an insert example:

```
INSERT INTO [ZHMIA1A] (
    RefID
    , Col_1
    , Col_2
    , Col_3
    ...
    ...
    ...
    , Col_120
    , Col_121
    , Col_122
)
VALUES (
    '19455642'
    , 'A'
    , 'A'
    , 'B'
    ...
    ...
    ...
    , 'A'
    , 'J'
    , 'T'
)
```

Comment: Need details on how are you inserting your data? If you have direct insert query doing this, pls share the same. If you are passing time part also in your data, this should work without any problems.

Comment: Does this problem usually happen at midnight?

Comment: Was column [RecTime] ever of type [DATE]?

Comment: @SachinShanbhag : no, data is never passed to the column [RecTime]

Comment: @MarkByers : no the problem happen randomly

Comment: @DanielPPCabral : no the column was created as DATETIME ( i have the scripts )

Comment: @armen - Can you show your insert query?

Comment: Is there an external application updating this table, subsequent to the inserted record? Eg. There could be a .NET application which updates the RecTime field using a DateTime object without time data.

Comment: @DanielPPCabral : no updates are not allowed on this table

Comment: Try to use sql server profiler to watch for any inserts or updates on this table. Maybe there is an insert which explicitly sets the RecTime ,hence this means the default value won't be used.

Comment: Look at the insert trigger - it looks like it's only inserting a DATE, not the entire DATETIME

Comment: Is there a trigger on this table? If so, look in there.

Comment: No trigger , no extra application , traced, everything goes fine on the production server till this hour , the bad thing is it's not predictable when it's going to happen again. After a little analysis the occurrence is not constant. Some days have 3-4 times, other times it's once every 2-3 days. I'm going mad !
will continue the research on this and keep you informed !
thank you all for the advices !

Comment: @armen - Is there no way to track all insert queries and do analysis based on that?